# Mounting Computer Under Particle Board Desk

Tags: wood, desk, table, mount, particle-board

I would like to mount a computer under a desktop made from particle board, the desktop is 1/2 inch thick, the computer plus mount weighs about 25lbs. Would the particle board hold?

How could I mount the computer to the underside of the desk and ensure it doesn't fall and break?

Comment: Are you sure the top is only 1/2" thick? Are you estimating or measuring? That's quite thin for a desktop and will be challenging to mount to.

Comment: It's 1/2" thick, just verified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's no problem mounting things to particle board as others have described, 1/2" is just too thin to work with. **I would mount another board under your desk using construction or wood glue, at least doubling the current thickness of the top.**

After that has set up for a day, I'd mount with 3/4" screws (or longer, depending on final thickness), properly piloted.

I've mounted many things to 3/4" particle board from below, including dual coat hooks that my kids have used for years. 1/2" just doesn't offer enough grab. It's likely that the screws will pull out a layer of material when it all comes crashing down.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the desks in cubicles and modular furniture are made of particle board and they are able to assemble and mount things with screws, so it should not be a problem.  They use special coarse thread screws that are made for particle board.

[image: furniture screw]

They make all kinds of under desk mounts - here's one:

[image: under desk mount]

The thickness of the material will limit the length of screw you can use;  with thin materials, you may need to use more screws for a given task.  I'd say as long as you get four screws in, you'll be safe with a 25 pound computer.

Comment: This sounds good, but I'd add, use the thickest screw your computer mount supports and predrill the holes before screwing.  Wrap your drill bit with tape just under 1/2 inch to be sure you don't drill too far.

Comment: I agree with your answer except that you'd almost never see screws in tension into such thin material. I wouldn't trust it, even with #14 screws.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are good ..just in case you still worry, you also can drill through the board and use a screw, big washer and nut to secure. My tip: if your particle board is bigger than the computer, make sure it is supported by a good structure around it, or your board will bend over time.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I don't feel comfortable screwing the mounts into just the particle board, I'm gonna see if I can use bolts from the top down. The tables have trim that goes over the edges, I'll see if this trim can hide the bolts.